# Does pgrouting support multi-modal routing?

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, routing, transit

Is it true that pgRouting cannot model multi-modal (including public transport) routing as it does not support multi-modal routing?

Answer (score 2):

No it is not true, although it depends on how you define multi-modal routing and how realistic a model you need. It's not exactly straightforward, but it is possible. My masters thesis used pgRouting to model public transportation accessibility, including walking, buses, trains, and a funicular. The most difficult aspects are modelling waiting for transport, including frequency of service, and modelling transfers between routes. It takes a lot of consideration of topology, including the construction of special, very small edges to enforce temporal penalities: because only edges can hold costs.

If schedules are really important (rather than some kind of generalised transit accessibility), you're better off using [GTFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Transit_Feed_Specification) and [OpenTripPlanner](http://www.opentripplanner.org/).

Answer (score 1):

There was a Google Summer of Code project to support Multi-Modal routing and import the data from GTFS format, but it was not developed further and currently isn't integrated into a release.

You can find the source code in a branch of the pgRouting repository, but it will need some work to make it work with the current version of pgRouting.
More information on the following Wiki page: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/Multi-modal-Public-Transit-Routing